# Background Audio for Web App

Tags: html, audio, web-applications

I'm making a cross-platform Web app That uses `HTML5-CSS3-JS ES6` and compiled with [Electron API](http://electronjs.org/) 
I want to use a background sound in main process so it doesn't stop and replaying from beginning every time that page changes
I want to know

1. How to add such a background sound
2. How to add a button or something else to control sound volume only and nothing more - that comes with HTML5 audio tag like seek and play-pause button-

Everywhere I looked, just got tips for audio tags that were not useful to me.

thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio tag is just a UI wrapper on top of the HTMLAudioElement. You simple use the Audio() to create a background audio element in the render process.

```
backgroundPlayer  = new Audio(src); //Create a background element.
backgroundPlayer.volume = value; //Between 0.0 and 1.0
```

You can create a second hidden BrowserWindow instance and use IPC to manupulate the audio element created inside it.

[The Mozilla Docs Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement) has comprehensive details on the Audio() element.

Comment: that's OK but I couldn't find a way to play on main script so it stops when page changes thank you - For Second question , Thank you again It works